# ASP.NET MVC 3 - redirect to another action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I want to redirect the Index action of the Home controller to another controller's action and nothing else. My code is thus:

```
    public void Index()
    {
        //All we want to do is redirect to the class selection page
        RedirectToAction("SelectClasses", "Registration");
    }
```

Right now, this just loads a 0 kB blank page and does nothing. I have a feeling it has something to do with that void return type, but I don't know what else to change it to. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Your method needs to return a `ActionResult` type:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //All we want to do is redirect to the class selection page
    return RedirectToAction("SelectClasses", "Registration");
}
```

Comment: And in case you need to pass some parameters:
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = 99, name= "sample" });

Answer (score 20):

You will need to return the result of `RedirectToAction`.

Answer (score 15):

Should [Return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470594.aspx) [ActionResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx), instead of Void

Answer (score 11):

You have to write this code instead of return View(); :

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");
```

Comment: would help if you provide some context and explanation as to why this would work.