# MVC 3 Redirect not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, redirecttoaction

I have a small problem related to action redirecting. I want to prevent users from being able to access information concerning a specific area in the site using an override of the OnActionExecuting in my BaseController class, which is the base class for all my controllers. Method body:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated && (User as Eagle.Security.EaglePrincipal != null) && Session != null && Session["LastKnownGoodArea"] != null && filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName != "InvalidPermission")
        {
            var currentArea = Principal.CurrentCenter.CODEFORM_CSE;
            if (currentArea != Session["LastKnownGoodArea"].ToString())
                RedirectToActionPermanent("InvalidPermission", "Account", new { target = 0, redirectURL = null as string });
            else
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }

    }
```

However, this does not redirect to the specified action. What am I doing wrong? What other approach, if any, would you guys suggest?

Thanks,
Silviu

Comment: see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909670/asp-net-mvc-3-redirect-to-another-action

Comment: Well, this is not really an option, since in some cases i just want to call the base class (Controller) OnActionExecuting, which has void as return type, and that is exactly how it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What Dave commented is right ! In addition this should be the syntax you are looking for :-**

```
 protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated && (User as Eagle.Security.EaglePrincipal != null) && Session != null && Session["LastKnownGoodArea"] != null && filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName != "InvalidPermission")
            {
                var currentArea = Principal.CurrentCenter.CODEFORM_CSE;
                if (currentArea != Session["LastKnownGoodArea"].ToString())
                {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                    RouteValueDictionary(new
                    {
                        controller = "InvalidPermission",
                        action = "Account",
                        target = 0,                                         
                    }));
                filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(filterContext);
                }       
                else
                {
                    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Well, from both your suggestions combined, and a finishing touch by yours truly, I made it work!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to prevent users from being able to access information concerning a specific area in the site using an override of the OnActionExecuting in my BaseController class, which is the base class for all my controllers.

Why did you choose to use OnActionExecuting for this? You're executing this if-statement on every request, I would recommend to use the `Authorize` attribute for the specific actions:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var user = User as Eagle.Security.EaglePrincipal;

        if(httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && user != null)
        {
            var currentArea = Principal.CurrentCenter.CODEFORM_CSE;
            var lastKnownArea = Session["LastKnownGoodArea"];

            if (lastKnowArea == null)
               return false;

            return currentArea.Equals(lastKnownArea.ToString());
        }

        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);            
    }
}
```

In your `web.config` you can configure redirects like:

```
 <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="/InvalidPermission/Account" />
 </customErrors>
```

If you want control over the UnAuthorized request you can always choose to override the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method

Comment: Well, this would be a nice solution, I give you that, but this would mean i would have to add the newly attr to all my methods, and I really don't feel like it. But i will keep this as future reference. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, you can always assign the attribute to the controller if all the methods are in the same controller.

Comment: The current architecture has the methods spread across several (read tens, maybe close to 100) controllers. But!!! they all inherit from BaseController. Let me see if I can somehow implement your idea in this class, and see if it propagates down the chain. If so, this would look exquisite to have, and i will follow your lead on this matter. Will get back with test results ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final solution:

```
var currentArea = Principal.CurrentCenter.CODEFORM_CSE;
            if (currentArea != Session["LastKnownGoodArea"].ToString())
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                    RouteValueDictionary(new
                    {
                        controller = "Account",
                        action = "InvalidPermission",
                        area = "",
                        target = 0,
                        redirectURL = ""
                    }));
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            }
```

Thank you both for your input, you helped alot!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect to Action from a filter because it is not creating an Action Result yet. You can only create a new route. I'm not completely sure of syntax you need. I threw this together as an example of way to go.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated && (User as Eagle.Security.EaglePrincipal != null) && Session != null && Session["LastKnownGoodArea"] != null && filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName != "InvalidPermission")
        {
            var currentArea = Principal.CurrentCenter.CODEFORM_CSE;
            if (currentArea != Session["LastKnownGoodArea"].ToString())
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
    new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary {
        {"controller", "InvalidPermission"}, {"action", "Account"}, {target =0}, {redirectURL = null as string }

            else
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }

    }
```