# View error when invoking methods from base controller in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance

I have the following controllers

```
public class StoreController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
            var model = new SomeViewModel();
            return View(model);
     }
}
```

and

```
public class SofiaStoreController : StoreController
{
    public ActionResult GetIndex(string city)
    {
        return base.Index();
    }
}
```

When invoking the base Index method from the derived class I get this error:

> The view 'getindex' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched:

Seems the GetIndex() method looks for a view in the derived controller's view folder by default even though no View() method is called but since there isn't such the error occurs.

Any idea why the method implicitly looks for a view and how to overcome the error ?

EDIT: After spending some time research the problem I came across these two posts: http://howtoprogram.eu/question/asp-net-c-asp-net-mvc-inherited-controller-using-base-view,2445 and http://www.davidwhitney.co.uk/Blog/2010/01/19/asp-net-mvc-view-engine-that-supports-view-path-inheritance/ Seems that controller inheritance is not that popular or straightforward decision. The solutions to my problem could be :
1. Not to use controller inheritance
2. Creating a custom view engine as shown in the second link (advanced)
3. As other people mentioned bellow - using full path to the view or RedirectToAction also could work

Comment: What is the reason behind SofiaStoreController inheriting from StoreController?

Comment: I have an abstract Store class with an abstract factory method. Then SofiaStore and other classes inherit it and override the factory method. Instead of relying on strings to initialize a store class thought it was a better idea to have a base StoreController and to inherit from it. Each derived store controller initialize different store class.

Comment: one option is to try redirecting instead http://stackoverflow.com/a/4909715/2048391

Answer (score -1):

It does look for a view based on the Action method name you originally called. You can always override this behavior if you use the overloaded View() method that accepts the view name/path:

```
public class StoreController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string viewName = "Index")
    {
        var model = new SomeViewModel();
        return View(viewName, model);
    }
}

public class SofiaStoreController : StoreController
{
    public ActionResult GetIndex(string city)
    {
        return base.Index();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now  I have this error : The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/sofiastore/Index.cshtml
~/Views/sofiastore/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml . The GetIndex method keeps on searching views in the Views/SofiaStore folder where I have nothing. My views are in the Views/Store folder where I already have Index.cshtml

Comment: That was just an example how to override which view should be used. I don't know your view files. You can also pass a path instead of just a name eg. "~/Views/existing-folder/exisitng-file.cshtml"