# How to force user sign out on lockout in MVC5

Tags: asp.net, identity, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using .Net MVC5 with Identity and am new to dev in general so bear with me.

How can I show lockout page and force user to log out based on the lockout status?

For testing purposes I made two users, one in Role "Admin" and another in Role "RegisteredUser".

I made an Ajax action that enable/disables and sets lockout to DateTime.MaxValue just for testing for specific "RegisteredUser". Its hooked up in some View just for admins.

If some "RegisteredUser" is locked out by "Admin" while signed in I want to show that "RegisteredUser" a lockedout page on his next request or at the very least 60 min later.

Now I've heard of AuthorizationFilter and ActionFilter or maybe some event handlers in Global.asax. But maybe there is already some mechanism to disable users and immediately is reflected on targeted user role?

How to best implement this problem of locking/disabling users with immediate enforcement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a base controller that implements [OnActionExecuting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting(v=vs.118).aspx).  At that point you can check if the user needs to be [redirected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909670/asp-net-mvc-3-redirect-to-another-action) to a lockout screen.

Comment: Hmm.... this certainly is a way to do it but I went with another solution because I didn't want to check the database constantly.

Answer (score 2):

While locking out user I also changed the SecurityStamp which will cause the auth cookie to be invalidated. Integrated Identity 2.0 mechanism which can be found in Startup.Auth checks for cookie integrity every (default: 30 min) and signs out user if not valid (e.g. has cookie with different SecurityStamp). The time delay for checks can be changed but I think its just right for my project.

This part of code invalidates some users cookie and I scheduled some check on a daily basis which will fire it if true;

```
var userManager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var user = userManager.FindByName(username);

userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, true);
userManager.SetLockoutEndDate(user.Id, DateTime.MaxValue);
user.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");
userManager.UpdateSecurityStamp(user.Id);
```

The part responsible for cookie validation and/or regeneration is already there but it seams present only from Identity 2.0 if I'm not mistaken. It's configuration is in the Startup.Auth.cs file and looks something like this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
});
```

I found all this here on stackoverflow in different articles so credit goes to those people.

Kevin Raffay's answer is certainly working so I will mark it as answer since I am new to this and I am not really sure which approach is better.

Comment: under which function i need to write this line userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, true); ?

Comment: How about if the user login using another browser. how to force the user to logout?